# Ubuntu 14.04 desktop and Android Studio compatibility

Tags: android, android-studio

I am intending to upgrade my development system in the new year and use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS as the OS. I also need to switch to Android Studio for Android development. I note that the Linux system requirements for Linux state

> GNOME or KDE desktop

**Ubuntu 14.04 has the Unity 7 as the normal desktop. Will this work correctly with Android Studio?**

(I am not an expert in linux and have only limited experience of using it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I am using it at the moment. unity 7 is gnome. From [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(user_interface)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_%28user_interface%29):

> Unity is a graphical shell for the GNOME desktop environment developed by Canonical Ltd. for its Ubuntu operating system.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful to know. I was hoping for an answer like this which states that the author is "using it at the moment".

Comment: thanks! remember to install oracle jdk. see here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre